# TCP congestion-control mechanism

Tags: tcp, protocols

1. Despite the fact we know that TCP has congestion-control mechanism, what are other reasons that most companies and institutions use TCP not UDP for video conference calls or for live streaming?

Answer (score 0):

> ... most companies and institutions use TCP not UDP for video conference calls or for live streaming

This claim is not really true.
The most used protocol for transfer of *real time* audio and video is RTP , which uses UDP. This is true for all major protocols for such conferences, like SIP, H.323, WebRTC, XMPP... . Skype also tries to use UDP and falls back to TCP only in very restricted environment (i.e. firewalls). TCP might be used in connection with real time traffic to negotiate the endpoints for the RTP traffic.

TCP is usually not used for *real time* because it might have a longer latency which is bad if you are trying to have a dialog (i.e. phone and video calls). This latency problem is caused by the aim for reliability, i.e. it retries seemingly lost data and downgrades the used bandwidth if there is packet loss. UDP on the other hand does not care about this and packets are simply lost. Real time audio and video codecs just deal with this loss because for real time audio/video data which take too long can no longer be used anyway.

With *streaming* the situation is different. Since streaming is one-way a latency of even multiple seconds is usually acceptable. This means latency is less of concern. In this case one can use protocols aiming for reliability (TCP) and if you have a guaranteed delivery you can also use more efficient audio/video codecs because they don't have to deal with packet loss.